# get list of objects from tiles viewPreparer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles2

I create implementation of ViewPreparer for getting categories list. And I need to get this list at header.

This is my implementation

```
public class CategoryMenuViewPreparer implements ViewPreparer {

    @Override
    public void execute(Request request, AttributeContext attributeContext) {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();

        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

        attributeContext.putAttribute("categories", new Attribute(user.getCategories()));
   }
}
```

And this is my tiles-definition

```
<definition name="CategoryPage" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/DefaultTemplate.jsp" preparer="ua.uzhhorodteam.cactiportal.handlers.CategoryMenuViewPreparer">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Category | TTE Web Portal"/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/fragments/defaultHeaderFragment.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/fragments/defaultFooterFragment.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/categoryPage.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

So, how can I write categories list at header as menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get "categories" out using importAttributes like

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="categories">
<c:forEach var="c" items=${categories}>
    <c:out value="${c}"/>
</c:forEach>
```